# Regex: Match if strings starts with a letter or number and then

Tags: regex

I'm wanting to match a string if begins with either a letter or number, and from there I want to count the string (excluding whitespaces), and if it's over 5 characters, match it.

I believe I'm pretty close, my current regex is:

```
\s*(?:\S[\t ]*){5,}
```

What I need to add, is making sure the string starts with either a letter or number (or if it begins with a whitespace, make sure the following character is a letter or number.)

http://regex101.com/r/lD7mZ2/1

Comment: can you elaborate your question with sample data and desired output based on sample data which would be more helpful for correct answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the regex

```
  ^\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]\s*(?:\S[\t ]*){4,}
```

Example: http://regex101.com/r/lD7mZ2/4

**Changes made**

- `^` anchors the regex at the start of the string.
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]` matches letter or digit
- `{4,}` quantifies it minimum 4 times. The presceding `\w` makes length of minimum 5

OR

a shorter version would be

```
^\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]\s*(?:\S\s*){4,}
```

Comment: Small nitpick: `\w` also matches the underscore

Comment: @Bohemian I missed that. Corrected in the answer.

Comment: And I would replace `[\t ]` with simply `\s`